# How to protect HTTP Request Basic Authentication login - Android?

Tags: android, web-services, security, httprequest

Basically, the requests to my web service are HTTP Requests. I have a slight problem. I secure them using basic authentication. This is a problem because, this is the code:

```
httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
 new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password"),
 "UTF-8", false));
```

And, by using dex2jar and java decompiler, you can find out the credentials.. I've used proguard too, it doesn't seem to protect this either.

Are there any solutions to make it so that only the android app can use the web service, and that users sniffing or hacking the APK finding the web service URL unable to make calls as if they were android devices?

Thank you!

Comment: what about encrypting password ? public and private key methods?

Comment: The problem is, anybody can look at the obfuscated(proguard) source code by decompiling the APK. This way, they can just copy the key from the source code, if they find it. For a hacker, this cannot be that hard to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTTPS.  That is really the only solution if you want secure http communication.  Anything else and you're pretty much exposing your user's credentials to anyone who is interested enough to look.

Comment: I've made a self-signed certificate and set up SSL, but I don't understand how this will help, can you explain? It's easy enough to find the webservice URL in the decompiled APK, all they have left is to search for the basic authentication login and password which will be visible too in the obfuscated source code.

Comment: Hello Kevin, I know it's time that his question was given as resolved, but I have the same problem and would like to know how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use code obfuscation that is scramble your code so it is no longer readable

You can add certificates and do much security from backend as all android code is visible like adding multiple tokens and storing them in preferences of app.
Also each networkrequest is to be encrypted with some algorithm so that any network spy is also gone away.

Try to make a security procedure that uses accepted methods and relies on randomised security data on the spot rather than compiling security values like some keys or auth codes.

You can also download some app data into cache which includes some authentication helpers which doesn't come with apk.

Lastly,Never store password , ask user every time.